# Cross-Origin Request Cors in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, request, cors

I want to fetch my NodeJS server, but I receive a Cross-Origin Request echec.

This is my index.js server :

```
const express = require('express')
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') require('dotenv').config()

const routerIdeas = require('./routes/ideas')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
    res.send(200)
    next()
})

app.use('/api', routerIdeas)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port : ${PORT}`)
})
```

I also tried with the npm CORS package but it's the same problem :

```
const express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') require('dotenv').config()

const routerIdeas = require('./routes/ideas')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.use('/api', routerIdeas)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port : ${PORT}`)
})
```

And this is my fetch by the React app :

```
useEffect(() => {
        const getIdeas = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true)
            try {
                const response = await fetch("https://localhost:3004/api/ideas")
                const data = await response.json()
                setIdeasArray(data)
                setIsLoading(false)
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('getIdeas error: ', err, err.stack)
            }
        }
        getIdeas()
    }, [])
```

The browser's console always answer :
Blocking a Cross-Origin Request: the "Same Origin" policy does not allow viewing of the remote resource located at https://localhost:3004/api/ideas. Reason: CORS request failed.

Comment: This whole area is ***very*** well covered by previous questions and answers, have you done thorough searching and reading? What is the exact error you're getting? Are you sure you're not sending other headers? Are you responding to the OPTIONS request as well as GET?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was just a stupid error :

Wrong fetch URL => https://localhost:3004/api/ideas

Good fetch URL => http://localhost:3004/api/ideas

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use CORS node package ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors))

Comment: I also tried with the npm CORS package but it's the same problem